# Laravel model find other column

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to overwrite the Laravel model 'find' function?
When I use model::find() it search in for the 'id' column but my table doens't have a id column but a SubscriptionId colum.

I know I can use: `model::where('subscriptionId', $id)` but my queued jobs are not working right now..

Answer (score 2):

```
model::where('subscriptionId', $id)->first()
```

Make sure your subscriptionId is unique.
Let me know if my snippets code not working

Or

```
model::findOrFail($id, 'subscriptionId')
```

Comment: Like I said, my jobs are failing with the wrong primary key: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'id'. (SQL: select top 1 * from [Subscription] where [Subscription].[id] is null)`

Answer (score 1):

Find in Laravel searches the table based on the primary key.  If you are not using `id` as your key, you can tell Laravel this within your model.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'subscriptionId';
```

This will tell Laravel to search this model based on the `subscriptionId` primary key instead of `id`.  This should solve it for you.  [Docs on Primary Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent)

Comment: I tried: 
`class Subscription extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv1';

    protected $table = 'Subscription';

    protected $primaryKey = 'SubScriptionId';

    public $incrementing = false;

    public $timestamps = false;
...
`

But my jobs are failing with this message: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'id'. (SQL: select top 1 * from [Subscription] where [Subscription].[id] is null)`

Comment: There is a whole lot of stuff you are doing that falls a bit outside convention.  Not a problem, but it may lead to confusion somewhere.  Is your table really called `Subscription` and not `subscriptions`?  Is it `subscriptionId` or `SubScriptionId` or `SubScription_id`, and is it actually a string and not an int?  All are perfectly fine, but you've shown several different ways of referring to your data - perhaps there is a typo somewhere.  It is one of the reasons for keeping closer to convention - it helps prevent some of those types of issues :)

Comment: Yes the table is called `Subscription`, it isn't a table from Laravel but another software package. The column name is `SubscriptionId`, I changed in my code but it the error the same.

Comment: I understand.  Next thing to check - is your database aware that the primary key is not called `id`?  IE if you `show create table Subscription`, does it show the primary key as `SubscriptionId`?  Even if you tell Laravel to use the right key, if the DB is looking for `id`, it could be the issue.

Comment: Isn't `show create table Subscription` a MySQL query? The database is a MS SQL database, so I used: "Script Table As" / "Create to". And I found `SubscriptionId` is the primary key.

Comment: Yes, MYSQL - the point was to see what the key was, which you did.  The error is pretty clear that something is not getting the message that `subscriptionId` is the key.  Only other thing that is remotely possible is to check to see if there is either an override on the class, or possibly the route is using the wrong class (similar named perhaps).  IE is it possible that the class where you have declared the `SubscriptionId` is not the class that is calling the query?

Comment: I checked it twice but it's the same class, the problem is in queing a mail. When I change it from queue to send directly there is no error..